# Resources for Promotion/Demotion Strategies for ML Item Recommendation Systems?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model, recommender-system, reference-request, research

We are looking to design a system where specific items or categories of items can be boosted/promoted up or relegated/demoted down the recommendation order.

What are the common strategies or standards to do such?

A cursory google search did not yield anything super-useful. Though this seems like a common problem in e-commerce. We are looking into Amazon Personalize on AWS as one option.

What is this area called in literature, is there standard name used in the field/industry?

Are there introductory or survey papers?

Answer (score 1):

One option is what I did on a project for an e-commerce website. Items were recommended based on similarity scores to other items. The similarity scores were based on item embeddings. People could pay to "boost" their item in the recommendations, this was done by adding a value to the similarity score based on how much they paid the e-commerce website.